# Group by List in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a List of following class:

```
public class PostOrderDataModel
{
    public string OCN { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string VerticalTypeName { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> VerticalTypeQuantity { get; set; }
}
```

having multiple instances with same OCN:

```
List<PostOrderDataModel> lstPostOrderDataModel = new List<PostOrderDataModel>();

lstPostOrderDataModel[0] = new PostOrderDataModel { OCN = "AX", Quantity = "1", VerticalTypeName = "Internet", VerticalTypeQuantity = null} ; 
lstPostOrderDataModel[1] = new PostOrderDataModel { OCN = "AX", Quantity = "2", VerticalTypeName = "Video", VerticalTypeQuantity = null}; 
lstPostOrderDataModel[2] = new PostOrderDataModel { OCN = "BX", Quantity = "2", VerticalTypeName = "Phone", VerticalTypeQuantity = null};
```

Now, I want to make a new list of PostOrderDataModel and fill the VerticalTypeQuantity dictionary with VerticalTypeName as `key` and Quantity as `value`, grouped by OCN. I tried this but this way i am only able to get one item against Key. How can I access both(VerticalTypeName,Quantity) items and add it to my dictionary `VerticalTypeQuantity`?

```
var results = lstPostOrderDataModel.GroupBy(
    p => p.OCN,
    p => p.VerticalTypeName,
    (key, g) => new { OCN = key, VerticalTypeName = g.ToList() });
```

Above code gives me the VerticalTypeName only against each OCN. I want the Quantity too so I can add in my dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element selector should be `p => p` instead of `p => p.VerticalTypeName`. once done, you can then populate the `VerticalTypeQuantity` as follows:

```
 var results = lstPostOrderDataModel.GroupBy(
                p => p.OCN,
                p => p,
                (key, g) => new { 
                       OCN = key, 
                      VerticalTypeQuantity = g.ToDictionary(e => e.VerticalTypeName,  
                         e => e.Quantity) 
                });
```